# I accidently removed visudo from /usr/sbin/ How do I recover it?

Tags: 20.04, sudo, windows-subsystem-for-linux, visudo

I was trying to install cypress in wsl.
While I was following the official documentation of cypress to install in wsl, I accidently removed the visudo from /usr/sbin/
Without it I cannot install and work it out properly.

Comment: What is it preventing you from doing, exactly? You should still be able to run the `sudo` command itself (so for example `sudo apt install --reinstall sudo` - which should replace the missing `visudo`)

Comment: @steeldriver I just tested (on a WSL instance I don't mind losing, of course ;-)), and `sudo apt install --reinstall sudo` doesn't recreate a missing `/etc/sudoers`.  I'm sure there's an `apt` construct that will force the recreation, but in the meantime, a `purge` first followed by a new install seems to work.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds how did you infer that the OP has a missing /etc/sudoers?

Comment: @steeldriver Oh drat, I misread ...

Comment: @steeldriver But I am making an assumption that, if they say they can't reinstall, that they already made a change to `sudoers` (via `visudo`) that prevents them from running as `sudo`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are unable to use `sudo` to reinstall `visudo`, it sounds like you may have removed your regular user from the `sudoers` as well.

WSL makes it fairly easy to recover, at least (in most situations).  From PowerShell, try running:

```
wsl -l -v
# Confirm that Ubuntu is your default distribution, then
wsl -u root sh -c "apt install --reinstall sudo"
```

The `-u root` argument to WSL allows you to run root commands from *outside* Ubuntu/WSL without requiring a password.  Note that this is not considered a security issue, since:

- Your Windows user already has access to everything in Ubuntu/WSL anyway
- The root user in WSL cannot exceed your *Windows* user's permissions anyway.

Comment: Thank You it worked